Flutter web app paused at web_entrypoint dart
web entry_point.dartI am new to flutter , and when I connected my project to firebase i kept getting this web enty_point.dart code
I tried clicking the play button to keep running the app , i dont know if there is other solutions, if i changed the database will the problem solve ?
this is the whole thing that shows up when i run my code code

Is your browser debugger opened?
please [edit] your question to an image

I cant add the whole image because I am new to stackoverflow , but I added the links , hope that help
